# Create a Sequence Diagram using the Obeo Uml-Designer Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, sequence, diagram

I have been working my way through the Obeo Uml-Designer plugin for Eclipse and it's been quite a learning curve!

Right now, I could use some help in creating a Sequence Diagram.  I'd like to add an existing Actor to the diagram to create a lifeline. I can't seem to drag it from the Model Explorer.  The Actor button under Existing Elements in the Palette brings up an empty list.

I think that I may need to create an Instance of my Actor, but I don't know how to do that. :-(

If I add a new Actor to the diagram, I can set the type by selecting the Actor from the "Semantic > Represents" dropdown in the properties.  However, this still shows the instance as null, as in "null : MyActor".

Any help would be most appreciated.  Thanks!

Rob

Answer (score 1):

I just tried with the 4.0.1 version, and I am able to use an existing actor or to create a new one.

I create my actor thanks to a use case diagram and then when I click on the "Existing elements -> Actor" tool, it opens a wizard which lists my actors. Then if i select one of them, it creates a lifeline for the selected actor and if I have a look on the properties view the lifeline represents the property associated to the actor which is automatically created by the "create actor" tool.

Are you using an older version of UML Designer ? And how did you create your actors?

For the drag & drop problem, no doubt, it is a bug. You can report an issue on github : https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues

You can find the detailed documentation on the UML Designer website : http://www.umldesigner.org/

Mélanie

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Melanie!

Comment: I am using version 3 for eclipse Kepler 4.3 because that is the version of eclipse that we use here at my work.  It comes prepackaged with certain plugins, including UML Designer 3. I tried installing version 4 but it really doesn't agree with Kepler.

I also created my actors in a Use Case diagram.

I'll submit the dragging issue on github and see what happens.

Thanks!

Rob

Comment: I think I found the problem.  The root element has to be a Model and NOT a Package. Although the dragging still doesn't work, I can add existing Actors using the Palette.

Comment: @RobGravelle welcome to Stack Overflow, now is probably the right time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: The root element could be a model or a package in the 4.0 version. If you need that the 4.0 version works on Kepler, you can submit a new issue on the issue tracker.